# results are not displaying after querying the database

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2005, jsp

trying to query mssql database using JSP. connected the database using ODBC
but this code is unable to print the result on screen .am using tomcat as a server.i don't know where am doing mistake. please help me to solve in this.

```
 <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
 <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>

<table border=6>
<tr><th>fname</th><th>lname</th></tr>


<%

  try{
  Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:ServerDB","","");
  Statement st=con.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from dbo.company");
  while(rs.next()){
 %>
 <tr><td><%=rs.getString("fname")%></td><td><%=rs.getString("lname")%></td></tr>
 <%
 }
    rs.close();
    st.close();
     con.close();
   }
   catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Exception in connecting to DB"+e.getMessage());}
   %>
  </table>
```

Comment: It is not a good practice to catch an exception and then do nothing about it. Print the output of the exception you catching in this block. That will show what is your problem.

Comment: @ Akshara: with the help of exception only, we can able to find out the error in your program. Update the Exception in your question.

Comment: am getting url and name in table. but not the values. its not showing any messages

Comment: @Akshara 1. Try to have database access code outside jsp. 2. Use jdbc like http: //jtds.sourceforge.net/ for accessing mssql from java. 3. show full exception stack.

Comment: Check your log files. Normally System.out or e.printStackTrace doesn't print the output directly to the JSP page. It writes the output to log files in the server. or just use out.println(e.getMessage());  ("out" is an implicit object in JSP and you can print directly to the html output using that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test the query independently i.e on database command line to make sure if error is in database environment,if it works fine 
else i guess problem would be

`Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:ServerDB","","");`

i never worked with MSSQL but in any database u gotta specify username and password which u left alone
Every thing in your code is just fine i guess problem is in connectivity!

### Revise your connectivity code or reinstall driver

Comment: i gave password and user name during odbc connections. and it works for other apllication.

Comment: I saw many problems with applications using jdbc:odbc connection
and particularly MSSQL and Oracle databases.
They work fine for some time and suddenly they show problems so that we get confused of our programming abilities if we are rookies.
Best database for student projects or websites which do not involve much transactions is 
MYSQL it is light and really good one we get mysql connector and it works fine almost always!
DB2 express C is not a bad option either! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown which exception is throwing your code but there some possibility from my side. I think after that your problem will be solved.

1. Have you created DSN for your database. If not then pleas create DSN for MSAccess database.
2. Create connection for this type...

   `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DSN_Name");`
3. SELECT query will be like this. After creating DSN you can use tablename directly.

   `SELECT * FROM table_name`

These specification are for MSAccess database.

If you are using MySql database then no need to create DSN. And use type four driver.